# Running SSH from a background script

Tags: linux, windows, bash, shell, ssh

I'm running SSH on Linux from a calling script that gets moved to the background upon execution.

The SSH command executes a batch command on remote win 10 server.
 The syntax in the calling script is: `chkval=$(SSH domain\remotehost cmd arg2 arg2)`.

This works from the command line or from calling script as long as I run the script in the foreground, but as soon as I place the script into the background or hand it off to "at" for scheduled exec, the SSH command fails with "more tokens expected" error.

The script doesn't die and neither does the SSH call, but it never executes the remote command.

Comment: Have you tried the option `-t` for acquiring a tty even in non-interactive sessions?

Comment: Yes, the SSH process just hangs and never executes the remote command. I can do a ps -ef |grep ssh and see it.

Comment: What is more, when I kill the calling process, it does not kill the related ssh command and I have to kill that separately.

Comment: Yeah, that's because signals aren't transmitted via the SSH protocol.  Only stdin, stdout, and stderr.  A signal to your local client will maybe kill the client, but not relay the signal to the server process on the remote host, so that server keeps on running and doesn't signal its children anything.

Comment: By the way, Thank you for your quick response and for the suggestion.

Comment: Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 0):

Yo can do that using the -N -f Flag.
From the man ssh

> -f: 
>       Requests ssh to go to background just before command execution.  This is useful if ssh is going to ask for passwords or passphrases, but the user wants it in the background.  This implies -n.  The recommended way to start X11 programs at a remote site is with something like ssh -f host xterm.
>       If the ExitOnForwardFailure configuration option is set to “yes”, then a client started with -f will wait for all remote port forwards to be success‐fully established before placing itself in the background.
>
> -N: 
>       Do not execute a remote command.  This is useful for just forwarding ports (protocol version 2 only).

Y leave an example script. Yo need first that the client/server authentication is key based as you dont need to put the user/password

```
#!/bin/bash
dst_machine_ip="192.168.0.100"
ssh  -Nf $dst_machine_ip

# Here goes your remote commands
ls
date
# Exit
ssh -O exit $dst_machine_ip
```

Yo can exec this script directly in background

`nohup ./script.sh &`

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I don't want to run the ssh command itself in the bg, but rather the calling process. Script calls ssh command and waits for remote commands to finish. then cleans up and exits. If I use the -f on the ssh command, it will go into the background and return control to the script before the remote process is done, which I don't want.

Comment: If I run the calling script in the fg, all is well, but that's not a workable solution. Sorry for the misunderstanding I know I said running SSH in the bg was the problem, but that wasn't exactly accurate.

Comment: Below is the script that calls the SSH command I call this script pmcmdx. I have another script which calls pmcmdx with the two arguments, I call that script "metaljpr". metaljpr is controlled by yet another master script which is the one placed into the bg at run time, I call that metal. Thus A Menu calls and sends metal into the bg, which runs >metaljpr >pmcmdx

Comment: fl=$1
wf=$2
   echo -e "\nInvoked at `date`"
   echo -e "\nAttempting SSH connection to Remote Integration Service: [PWIS01_SDW_DEV]"
   jstat=$(ssh NJ\\NJDSSINFADM@dc01nj2dwifdv02.nj.core.him pmcmds $fl $wf)
   let jstat=`echo $jstat|sed -e 's/[^0-9]//g'`
   if [ $jstat -eq 0 ]; then
      echo -e "INFO: Workflow [${2}]: Execution succeeded."
   else
      echo -e "ERROR: Workflow [${wf}]: Execution failed." 
      echo -e "Disconnecting from remote Integration Service"
   fi

Comment: here is the ssh command I'm running `code` /usr/bin/ssh NJ\\NJDSSINFADM@dc01nj2dwifdv02.nj.core.him pmcmds DFD_ETIME wf_TEST

Comment: If I put that command in a script and execute it, it runs fine. If I put an & at the end of the script on the command line, it runs fine. If I put the first script into a second shell script with an & after the script and call the second script from the command line, it does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Here is what I need to do: script_b contains "script_a &". script_a contains the ssh command above. I need to be able to run script_b from the command line but it does nothing. I get NO errors and the job on the remote machine, (a widows 2012 server btw), does not execute.